# How do I capture the data within an object/array that is hidden as a textContent of a specific element?

Tags: javascript, function, google-tag-manager, ajaxform, google-datalayer

```
<div id="ProductModal_10207555">
  <span class="ari-form">
    <span class="datasource hidden">  
      "{
         "itemid": "REF12345",
         "locationid": "54321",
         "leadValue": 15149,
         "productSku": "SKU12345",
         "itemYear": "2019",
         "itemMake": "Adidas",
         "itemModel": "Ultraboost",
         "itemPrice": "$139.00",
       }"
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

This is a hidden object from a form and I would like to extract the data in it. When I try to do DOM scraping I end up with a string value and it just shows me all the text that I am seeing in that specific object.

> "{"itemid": "REF12345","locationid": "54321","leadValue": 
>          15149,"productSku": "SKU12345","itemYear": "2019","itemMake": 
>          "Adidas","itemModel": "Ultraboost","itemPrice": "$139.00",}"

And what I would wish to capture is the " itemYear , " itemMake " and " itemModel " from this and hopefully send this entire string into a datalayer for Google Tag Manager where in I can capture each of those variables and their value separetely in Google Tag Manager. Is there a way to do this via native javascript as this is the language supported by GTM?

There are other **span class="datasource hidden"** within the site so I purposely put the parent alements in there since this is how we identify the element.

Sorry if this may be a quick one. I am still learning. Thank you.

Comment: use `const data = JSON.parse(your_string_variable)` then `data.itemPrice` will be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in JSON format *except* for the `"`s at the very beginning and end, and the `,` just before the `}`, so once you get the `textContent` of the element, you can slice out the `"`s, the last comma, and then parse it:

```js
const { textContent } = document.querySelector('#ProductModal_10207555 .datasource.hidden');
const json = textContent.match(/{[\s\S]+(?=,)/)[0] + '}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(
  obj.itemYear,
  obj.itemMake,
  obj.itemModel
);
```

```html
<div id="ProductModal_10207555">
  <span class="ari-form">
    <span class="datasource hidden">  
      "{
         "itemid": "REF12345",
         "locationid": "54321",
         "leadValue": 15149,
         "productSku": "SKU12345",
         "itemYear": "2019",
         "itemMake": "Adidas",
         "itemModel": "Ultraboost",
         "itemPrice": "$139.00",
       }"
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

`{.+(?=,)` means: match a `{`, then match as many characters as possible, until coming to the last `,`.

It's quite an odd way of storing data. Plain JSON would make much more sense.

Or, for the equivalent in ES5:

```js
var textContent = document.querySelector('#ProductModal_10207555 .datasource.hidden').textContent;
var json = textContent.match(/{[\s\S]+(?=,)/)[0] + '}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(
  obj.itemYear,
  obj.itemMake,
  obj.itemModel
);
```

```html
<div id="ProductModal_10207555">
  <span class="ari-form">
    <span class="datasource hidden">  
      "{
         "itemid": "REF12345",
         "locationid": "54321",
         "leadValue": 15149,
         "productSku": "SKU12345",
         "itemYear": "2019",
         "itemMake": "Adidas",
         "itemModel": "Ultraboost",
         "itemPrice": "$139.00",
       }"
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The language is unsupported in Google Tag Manager. So it is not working there. Also, I am looking to send those data individually into a dataLayer.

Comment: If you can't use `/s` to make dots match newlines, you can use `[\s\S]` instead

Comment: Is there a way we can do this in VanillaJS? Because this does not seem to be supported in Google Tag Manager.

Comment: The above *is* completely vanilla JS - what about it isn't supported? You can press "Run code snippet" to see it in action on your own browser, it will log `2019 Adidas Ultraboost` for you

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the error I get: " This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: const declaration."

I think the const is not supported in Google Tag Manager and sadly I cannot insert this code directly into the website. because my task is to use what ever I can within the site.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't even support ES2015? That's unfortunate. But it's easy to use `var` instead, see edit